# Why don't my modifications to django-admin templates show up?

Tags: python, django-admin

I don't seem to be able to modify the django.admin templates. I am following the [tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/).

I have the following directory structure in a Django project

```
|source-root
  |venv (this is the virtualenv directory)
  |mysite
    |mysite
      -__init__.py
      -settings.py
    |myapp
      -__init__.py
      -admin.py
      -models.py
      -etc.
    |templates
      |admin
        -base_site.html (modified from contrib/admin/templates/admin)
    -db.sqlite3
    -manage.py
```

In source-root/mysite/mysite/settings.py, I have added

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
print(TEMPLATE_DIRS)
```

When I go to source-root/mysite and type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I see

```
['.../source-root/mysite/templates']
```

This is already a bit odd as I would have expected to see

`[.../source-root/mysite/mysite/templates]`

The weirder thing is that when I modify `base_site.html`, the modifications are not seen when I actually access the site. What do I need to do to see the modified tempate?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect to see `mysite/mysite`? The `BASE_DIR` is `source-root/mysite`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates):

> Within this admin directory, create sub-directories named after your app....
>
> For example, if we wanted to add a tool to the change list view for all the models in an app named my_app, we would copy contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html to the templates/admin/my_app/ directory of our project, and make any necessary changes.

So it should really be `source-root/mysite/templates/admin/mysite/base_site.html`.